# How do I execute a jMeter script in java and process results in the same program?

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to execute a jMeter script within a java program, and then process the results (Specifically trying to get an assertion). I found resources on creating a script within java and then executing, but none on executing a premade jmx and then processing the results directly.

Any links to helpful resources is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found a code example, but it doesn't work. [link](https://hiromia.blogspot.com/2016/07/how-to-run-jmeter-load-testing-script.html)

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, I had spent a lot of time to get it to work. And even if some part of it works but then you don't have enough documentation to run it fully for your testing purpose. Instead, run the JMX (configure the JMX to save the results/assertion values in XML/JTL file) file by running the command using your Java code. Once done you can open the JTL file in JMeter to see the results. If that seems to be a hassle and you like to write code than create a parser to parse the JTL file to extract the assertion results.